# Fixed and fluid divs in col-12-xs column withouth collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put two fixed width divs and one fluid width div in one row of col-12-xs. I want this fluid div to fill out whole space left, but with min-width (for example 600px).

I did something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12-xs">
      <div class="event">
        <div class="date">
        </div>
        <div class="flyer">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.date, .flyer, .info {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100px;
}

.date, .flyer {
  width: 100px;
}

.info {
  min-width: 600px;
}
```

It works fine, but when I decrease window size this .info div moves to next row, which is not what I want.

How can I fix this?

http://www.bootply.com/stF3byJ56I#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left` for `.info`

```
.date, .flyer, .info {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100px;
}
.date, .flyer {
  width: 100px;
  float:left;
}
.info {
  min-width:600px; 
}
```